# How to create a fading form on focus lost &got event

Tags: vb.net, winforms, focus, opacity

I am doing project in vb.net
When i click on button open I opened form with no control box(minimize,maximize etc).set borderStyle to FixedToolWindow
I want to change the opacity of form on got focus & lost focus event.
I also used activated & deactivated event but doesnt working

```
   Private Sub form_Deactivate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)HandlesMyBase.Deactivate
     Me.Opacity =0
      End Sub

   Private Sub form_Activated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles  MyBase.Activated
        Me.Opacity = 1
    End Sub
```

Comment: You have to describe the not working part.  The code you posted is "ok", so the problem is somewhere else.  BTW, Opacity should be 1, not 100.  It's a double.

Comment: How are you opening the second form, can you post that code?

Comment: @Kerry H by using form.showDialog() method.

Comment: @LarsTech Sorry by mistake i did this.I edited  this one

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to use a System.Windows.Forms.Timer. the implementation is very simple:

- Have two variables called _fromOpactity and _toOpacity, and a constant OpacityStep = 0.05
- on Form Activate or Deactivate set _fromOpacity and _toOpacity and start the timer to fade in/out.
- In the timer Elapsed event handler, Increment or Decrement OpacityStep (depending on from/to) until the desired value is reached.

For a full example of how to do this, see this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/FadeInFadeOutForm.aspx).

Best regards,

Comment: Andrew Burnett-Thom .Yes i know it its fine.but i want it on got & lost focus which event not responding .

Comment: Ah ok, I misread your question. I thought you were asking how to fade a form, but you are asking why the Deactivate and Activate events don't fire. May I suggest rephrasing the question to "Deactivate, Activate, Events not firing in VB.NET" or similar? Best regards,

Comment: Do you know any trick to do this.If focus is on the form then its opacity is 1 & if focus is outside then to set opacity to 0

Comment: Try mouse enter, mouse leave? I will search around to try to work out why activate etc doesn't fire

Comment: @ Dr. Andrew Burnett-Thompson Sorry but mouse enter & mouse Leave events also not working.

Comment: How are you subscribing to the events? Can you post a code example (project) with the failing code on PasteBin? I've never heard of a Winforms project where MouseEnter/Leave, Deactivate/Activate and Focus/LostFocus *all* don't fire!

Answer (score 1):

Try **0.01** in your 2nd line. You used **0** and it will hide your form.

Because that when you click in form area , the form_Actived don't run.

Comment: sorry @Moctava Farzán but its not working.I dont know why this is happening

Comment: Okay. Set **TopMost** of the form **true** then try again. I hope this works :-)